# UWP Code Signing

Tags: c#, certificate, uwp

I want to use **System Center Configuration Manager** in my Application. [This Msdn article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt595710.aspx) says that

> Universal Windows Platform line of business apps **must be signed with a code-signing certificate** that is trusted on each device to which the app is deployed. You can use certificates **from an in-house PKI infrastructure**, or a **certificate from a third-party** public root certificate installed on the device.

My question is how to get a code signing certificate and how to sign my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've basically got two options. You can either create a test certificate that you're going to have to deploy on every machine that you intend to deploy your app to, or get a 3rd party certificate from a trusted source. I'd prefer to not give names of 3rd parties, but if you do a Bing search for "Code Signing Certificate", you should find some options.

MakeCert.exe is an application in the Windows SDK that you can use to make a test certificate. The process to install it on every test machine is somewhat laborious, but it's an option. Otherwise, when you go with a 3rd party, they'll give you a certificate that you won't have to manually install.

In either case, once you've got the certificate, you'll want to use SignTool on your AppX package. SignTool is also part of the SDK. There's documentation on how to use it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835835(v=vs.85).aspx).

I hope this solves your issue.

--Dante [MSFT]

Comment: Can you upload an uwp app that is signed with a 3rd party certificate to the MS Private app store? I get an 'Invalid package family name' error. @dante-gagne

Comment: You did not really explain whether you need EV or normal certificate. More detailed answer is needed regarding 3rd party certs